# Les constructions « être interprété/perçu/vu comme » sont-elles idiomatiques?

Tags: constructions, formulation-idiomatique, formulation

Au sens de «Être regardé comme ».

Exemple:

Ton absence à la fête de l’entreprise pourrait être regardée comme un manque de respect et un désengagement.

Ton absence à la fête de l’entreprise pourrait être interprétée/perçue/vue comme un manque de respect et un désengagement.

Je me permets de poser cette question car j’ai consulté le dictionnaire de l’Académie française et il ne semble pas répertorier les constructions en titre, il fait mention des constructions « regardé comme », « considéré comme » et « cité comme » sans plus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Les trois variantes en titre me paraissent tout à fait idiomatiques, et même plus courantes que *pourrait être regardée comme* qui est en perte de vitesse depuis un moment, ce que confirme Google Ngram:

[image]

Une recherche ouverte pour identifier les verbes les plus couramment utilisés dans ce type d'expression montre que *considérer* se détache assez nettement.

[image]

*Considérer* correspond bien au sens de ta phrase dont une forme très idiomatique est donc aussi :

> Ton absence à la fête de l’entreprise pourrait être considérée comme un manque de respect et un désengagement.

Answer (score 0):

*Les définitions du TLFi*

> [**regarder comme**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/regarder) 2. Regarder qqc./qqn comme, en (rare). Considérer comme, en tant que, tenir pour.
> ♦ [+ adj.] Je demandais certaines choses qui ne m'étaient pas encore suffisamment garanties pour que je pusse regarder la chose comme faite.  (Gobineau, Corresp.[avec Tocqueville], 1855, p. 229)

> [**interpréter** comme](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/interpr%C3%A9ter) 1. Donner un sens personnel, parmi d'autres possibles, à un acte, à un fait, dont l'explication n'apparaît pas de manière évidente. Synon. analyser, comprendre.
> ♦Interpréter un phénomène, un événement de diverses façons; interpréter un comportement, une expression du visage, une phrase, un silence.
> ♦ Il me semblait qu'on pouvait interpréter le décret en question non **comme** une preuve que la guerre serait courte, mais **comme** l'imprévoyance qu'elle le serait. (Proust, Temps retr.,1922, p. 744)
> ♦ Il feignit d'interpréter comme un congé le regard surpris, vaguement soupçonneux de son chef (Bernanos, Crime,1935, p. 776)

> [**percevoir** comme](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/percevoir) B.− Saisir, prendre connaissance par l'intuition ou par l'entendement. Synon. discerner, saisir.
> ♦ Il percevait chez elle à des profondeurs secrètes, des mouvements hors de la volonté en Dieu de son directeur, mouvements courts et craintifs, qui n'osaient aboutir, mais qu'il sentait qu'elle refoulait. (Goncourt, MmeGervaisais,1869, p. 228)
> ♦ L'homme perçoit Dieu en son cœur (Béguin, Âme romant.,1939, p. 93)

> [**voir** comme](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/voir) **d)** [Implique une disposition d'esprit qui met en jeu la subjectivité]
> **α)** Percevoir les choses d'une certaine façon, sous un certain aspect.
> ♦  Sur le point de quitter Paris, je voudrais le voir en étranger. Par exemple, noter le calme et la tranquillité imprévus de la plupart des gens pendant les deux mois qui ont suivi le 6 février (Larbaud, Journal, 1934, p. 301)

L'[ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%AAtre+regard%C3%A9+comme%2C%C3%AAtre+vu+comme%2C%C3%AAtre+per%C3%A7u+comme%2C%C3%AAtre+interpr%C3%A9t%C3%A9+comme&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C3%AAtre%20regard%C3%A9%20comme%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%AAtre%20vu%20comme%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%AAtre%20per%C3%A7u%20comme%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%AAtre%20interpr%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20comme%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C%C3%AAtre%20regard%C3%A9%20comme%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%AAtre%20vu%20comme%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%AAtre%20per%C3%A7u%20comme%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%AAtre%20interpr%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20comme%3B%2Cc0) suivant se limite à l'usage au passif des quatre formes. On voit qu'elles sont actuellement toutes utilisées avec la même fréquence.

[image]

[être regardé comme](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%C3%AAtre%20regard%C3%A9%20comme%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)
[être interprété comme](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%C3%AAtre%20interpr%C3%A9t%C3%A9e%20comme%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)
[être perçu comme](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%C3%AAtre%20per%C3%A7ue%20comme%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)
[être vu comme](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%C3%AAtre%20vue%20comme%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)

Dans les définitions « comme » ne fait partie d'une expression figée que dans le premier cas (regarder comme), et dans les deux dernier n'apparait pas dans les exemples.

À partir d'un examen des définitions et des pages de recherche Google correspondant aux formes on voit que l'on trouve les quatre au sens figuré et qu'elles sont idiomatiques. Cependant, on ne peut pas les concevoir en tant que synonymes exacts les unes des autres, ni même, parfois, comme commutables. Par exemple, lorsque « voir comme » a pour objet un nom concret, « interpréter comme » ne peut plus être substitué, mais ce n'est pas tout.

- Je n'avais jamais pensé que ma chambre pouvait être vue comme un prolongement de... euh... de notre créativité, enfin, tu vois ? ([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Un_beau_jour_peut_%C3%AAtre/TUxoAwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22%C3%AAtre+vue+comme%22&pg=PT164&printsec=frontcover))
- <s>Je n'avais jamais pensé que ma chambre pouvait être interprétée comme un prolongement de... euh... de notre créativité, enfin, tu vois ?</s> (*ni « interpréter », ni « percevoir », mais « regarder » convient*)

L'exemple suivant est encore plus révélateur de cette différence de sens.

- La nageuse Mélanie Henique montre plus de réserve et préfère être vue comme une sportive avant tout. « Je ne veux pas qu'on dise : “Tiens, c'est elle la ...
  ([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Joue_la_comme_Megan/V701EAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22%C3%AAtre+vue+comme%22&pg=PT119&printsec=frontcover))
- <s>La nageuse Mélanie Henique montre plus de réserve et préfère être interprétée comme une sportive avant tout. « Je ne veux pas qu'on dise : “Tiens, c'est elle la ...</s>